# Istio/Virtual service - Rewrite rule for URI with path parameter

Tags: kubernetes, networking, istio

What is the correct syntax for rewriting URI with a path parameter? I'd like to rewrite all requests matching

`/my-service/requests/{requestId}/history` (regardless of value of  `requestId` path parameter) to

`/requests/{requestId}/history`.

Please note there is already another rule for `/my-service/requests/send`.

Thanks

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: world
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - internal-gateway.istio-system
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/my-service/requests/send"
          ignoreUriCase: true
      rewrite:
        uri: "/requests/send"
      route:
        - destination:
            host: my-service.world.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8080
    - match:
        - uri:
            regex: "/my-service/requests/.*/history".   //<=for all path parameters  
          ignoreUriCase: true
      rewrite:
        uri: "/my-service/requests/{requestId}/history" //<=??????
      route:
        - destination:
            host: my-service.world.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: whether above virtualservice configuration is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Matches to URIs are evaluated in order, thus it can be configured like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: world
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - internal-gateway.istio-system
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/my-service/requests/send"
          ignoreUriCase: true
      rewrite:
        uri: "/requests/send"
      route:
        - destination:
            host: my-service.world.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8080
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/my-service/requests"
          ignoreUriCase: true
      rewrite:
        uri: "/requests"
      route:
        - destination:
            host: my-service.world.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: That does not answer the question about capture.